# Ubuntu 20.04 dock icons not working correctly

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons, dock

I am trying to fix an issue without any luck. Help is much appreciated. I installed ubuntu 20.04 just after release. After a couple of days, application icons in the dock stopped appearing while the application is running. I reinstalled ubuntu. It worked fine until yesterday. The same issue started again.

1. When I log in, the menu button in the dock does not work. I have to open it from the keyboard. After that, it works fine.
2. When I open an application, say chrome, it's icon does not appear in the dock. Please see the [image]screenshot.
3. Sometimes icon appears after some time but does not go away easily when I close the application.

I frequently use an external monitor. It started yesterday after I used the external monitor. I tried to remove monitors.xml from config but no luck. My laptop is HP Elitebook 840 G5. and monitor is HP 22f.

Comment: Having similar issue. In my case icons appear after a while when I boot and when starting and exiting it takes 5-8 sec to appear and disappear.